# Passing parameter to anonymous function in setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, anonymous-function

I am trying to figure out why the following code does not work

```
function testFunction(fn) {
    setTimeout(fn(1), 1000)
}

this.testFunction(id => console.log("id; " + id))
```

Removing `setTimeout()` and simply using `fn(1)` will console log the desired result

> id; 1

Comment: `fn(1)` you're calling `fn(1)` **immediately** - try `function testFunction(fn) {
    setTimeout(fn, 1000, 1)
}` instead

Comment: note, your first code example will output `id; 1` to the console - if you think it doesn't, then you've posted the wrong code - it just doesn't wait 1 second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jaromanda X points out in the comments, any parameters that need to be passed to the anonymous function must be passed to the `setTimeout` function rather than using brackets notation - `fn(1)` - as that invokes the anonymous function before it is passed to `setTimout`

```
function testFunction(fn) {
    setTimeout(fn, 1000, 1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function accepts an argument and as a consequence it is immediately invoked. Put the algorithm in an anonymous function.

```
setTimeout(() => fn(1), 1000)
```